# Google Form : How to not allow duplicate answer in Grid?

Tags: google-forms

Here form that I tried to do. I have 5 classes and I want to know what priority level of the classes from the student.I don't want them to select the same level priority to the different classes but I could not found this type of question pattern in Google Form.

I tried Grid type,it only allow one response per row, which is good for me.But it allow same answer for one column, which I don't want.Example a student can select Class 1 and Class 2 with the same Priority 1.

[image]

The answer that I expected from student only one priority for one class and this priority should different from other class.Is there anyway to achieve this in google form?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to solve this issue.

1. **Switch your Classes** to be the column heading and priority to be your rows.
2. **Click the small arrow** next to advanced settings at the bottom of question in edit mode. Click the box next to "Limit to one response per column."

Hope that helps!